# CSS-modules with storybook module not found

Tags: reactjs, configuration, babeljs, css-modules, storybook

I've installed in my react project storybook v5. Everything seems to be ok, but when I want to import styles to my react component (I use postcss-modules) I have an error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './styles/Buttons'`. 
What should I add to storybook config to make it workable? I use babel in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize Storybook’s `webpack` set up by adding `webpack.config.js`.

For example adding `SASS`:

```
// @ webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  // `mode` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
  // You can change the configuration based on that.
  // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

  // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  });

  // Return the altered config
  return config;
};
```

Check out the [docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#full-control-mode).